# django-compressor and nginx: 404 with compressed files

Tags: django, nginx, django-compressor

What a weird error. What I'm doing wrong?

All the files compressed by `django-compressor` in the `CACHE` folder return 404.
They exist in filesystem and can be downloaded via ftp.
They're seen when I access the `/static/` folder via the browser, but when I try access them, they throw a 404. This happens no matter if `COMPRESS_ENABLED` is `False` or `True`.
Their permissions are set to 755.

Regular css and js files return 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that nginx responded with a huge latency (I'm not sure why). 
It looks like I tried to access files which did not exist. After some amount of time (5-20 mins) they became accessible.
Probably Nginx - or caching - was not configured properly.