# compress.js made the CACHE directoly under uwsgi not nginx

Tags: javascript, django, nginx

I am using `Django Compressor` on `nginx` & `uwsgi`

I have each docker container for `nginx` & `uwsgi`

I copied static folder to `nginx:/static` and others to `uwsgi:/myapp/` in advance.

However `compress.js` made the compress file dynamically and set under `uwsgi:myapp/static/CACHE` of uwsgi container.

`<script src="/static/CACHE/js/output.b6723c2174c0.js">`

So consequently 404 not found for this file, because this request is redirect to nginx:/static not `uwsgi:/myapp/static`

How anyone solves this problem?

my nginx setting is below

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass  http://uwsgi:8001/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Whitebear. Have you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's about troubleshooting. There can be different issues.
Similar reported here [django-compressor and nginx: 404 with compressed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275718/django-compressor-and-nginx-404-with-compressed-files)

Having same issue I found that in settings.py the COMPRESS_ROOT was defined to the path which is not specified in the Nginx configuration.
Removing COMPRESS_ROOT fixed it. Refer to: [Django Compressor Quickstart](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation)